# Debian 8 and few questions about Graphical Firewall?

Tags: linux, firewalls

I have installed Debian 8 today, and so far so good. What I want to achieve now is to install firewall but can't find Firestarter in repos (discontinued ?). So, I have installed a GUFW and set it up.

After some time running GUFW, it spits out some errors and the Graphical Interface is closed. Because of that I'm afraid that my firewall might not work correctly. Is there any way I can test or check if my firewall is working correctly as it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the set of firewall rules that you have created, you can create tests for each of those rules. I accomplish this in organizational settings by using tools such as `hping` or `scapy`.

If you are familiar with the concept of unit tests, it works the same way. I run a listener on the protected host and send packets to it that have been crafted to test each rule in the rule set. In this way, you can test the effect of changes that you make, and ensure that your expectations are met at any point in time.

Comment: Ok sounds easy but how do I test for example incoming port 22 etc ? Sorry for such a stupid question but I have never used such tools before.

Comment: If you want to test port 22, just launch an ssh session from an external host

Comment: Ok but what about any incoming connections in general ?